# Android - getResources() and static

Tags: android, static

I've got a class

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
```

out of this I try to call a method from another class. This method contains:

```
mFoo.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange))
```

But it doesn't work. It tells me `getResources` isn't static... how can I change this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> But it doesnt work, it tells me, getResources isnt static... how can i change?

This means you are trying to call `getResources()` from a static method, rather than a regular (instance) method. The easiest thing to do in your case, if `mFoo` is a `TextView` or some other widget, is to call `getResources()` on the `Context` available from the widget:

```
mFoo.setTextColor(mFoo.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
```

However, the fact that you are trying to reference a widget named `mFoo` from a static method scares the crap out of me. This is just asking for a memory leak. I think you really need to reconsider your use of static data members and methods.

Comment: Thanks. My origin problem was, that I want to call a Method, belonging to myClass from the Class Preferences. So when a preference has changed, it has to call a method from a "foreign" class, maybe you could give me a hint, how to solve this?!

Comment: @Christoph: You do not want to be trying to update widgets of some other activity from your `PreferenceActivity`. Have your other activity register for preference changes using `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()`. When the preference changes, the activity is notified and can make the adjustments.

Comment: Ok, thats what i've done before, i thougt, there is a way to minimize the code in my "other activity", sourcing out the ChangeListener..